# Cleaning Oil/Grease on Felt Pool Table

Tags: equipment, pool, maintenance

I recently bought a used felt top pool table from someone that had it in their workshop.  They had started using it more like a table, so it got rather dirty with general debris, but also oil and grease.  What should I use to clean this without damaging the felt, specifically the oil and grease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would forget cleaning and get the table reclothed.  You may get the stains out, but the oils can damage the material in a way that can affect the playing surface.